# Calling function from another function - Javascript API

Tags: javascript, api-design

I'm new in javascript and I have a problem I can't solve.

In the beginning I had the following code, and worked just fine

```js
function foo(){
    var load_b = new Array();
    load_b = b();
}

function a() {
    var files = document.getElementById("images").files;
    return files;
}

function b(){
    var get_a = a.call(get_a);
    return get_a;
}
```

Now I'm trying to create an API, and the problem is that when I do `var get_a = a.call(get_a);` or `var get_a = a();`, I get an:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined(…).

I tried many different ways of calling a from b, but I always get an error. Currently my code looks like this. Do you guys have any ideas?

```js
function foo(){
    var new_api = new my_api();
    var load_b = new Array();
    load_b = new_api.b();
}

var my_api = function(){
    return {
        a : function a() {
            var files = document.getElementById("images").files;
            return files;
        },
        b : function b() {
            var get_a = a();
            return get_a; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You will have to learn to use the `this` object to access these functions - they are not declared globally, so the standard lookup of `window[a]` results in `undefined`. When doing this, you might want to look into `class` delcaration in JS instead of returning anonymous objects from your functions. Look into prototypes as well, as this way you are creating a new reference to a function _every_ time, while with prototype you only do it once (classes are just fancier prototypes, by the way).

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `this` to tell the script to look for the function within the current scope, not globally:

```
var get_a = this.a();
```

As a secondary point, this syntax is a little bit redundant:

```
a : function a() {
```

You don't need the second mention of "a":

```
a : function() {
```

will work.

Comment: Just for reference, it _is_ actually useful to use a named function declaration even if it is a copy - it will show up when you inspect elements (I have something that calls functions every frame and its great to see the array of functions listed as `myFunctionName(){}` even though it doesnt do anything. Helps in debugging, but thats it :) )

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to continue using your existing code, you have to change the line `var get_a = a();` to `var get_a = this.a();`.

The reason for this is that you want to specify that the function you're referring to, `a` is inside the parent object's scope. Without using `this`, JavaScript it by default looking in the current function scope, which means it's trying to find the `a()` function inside the `b` function, `b : function() { ... }`.

Note: I cleaned the code slightly, and replaced `document.getElementById("images").files` with a test array `['1', '2', '3']` so that this code runs in a fiddle setting. You can uncomment and change that line back later.

```
function foo() {
    var new_api = new my_api();
    var load_b = new_api.b();
    alert(load_b); // I added this here so this code outputs in a fiddle
}

var my_api = function() {
    return {
        a : function() {
            var files = ['1', '2', '3']; //document.getElementById("images").files;
            return files;
        },
        b : function() {
            var get_a = this.a();
            return get_a; 
        }
    }
}

foo(); // I added this here so this code executes in a fiddle
```

Answer (score 0):

Your object definition is a bit off. Here is how it should be done:

```js
function foo() {
  var new_api = new my_api();
  var load_b = new_api.b();
  console.log(load_b);
}

var my_api = function() {
  this.a = function() {
    return "the files"; // document.getElementById("images").files;
  };
  this.b = function() {
    return this.a(); // use this.a to make sure we access local a
  };
  // return the object with a and b both set as functions:
  return this;
}

foo();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var a = function() {
    return document.getElementById("images").files;;
};

var b = function() {
    return a() || [];
};

var foo = function() {
    var load_b = b();
};
```

Comment: This wasn't what the OP said was the problem - this bit was working. You answered the bit of the question that _wasnt_ a question.